# How is this question not closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, vote-to-close, question-quality

I'm quite frankly baffled that this question: [Need to change scale of numbers from (-1 to 1) to (1-10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50589970/need-to-change-scale-of-numbers-from-1-to-1-to-1-10) was upvoted and answered multiple times, instead of being close-voted as off-topic or criticized for its irrelevant tags and lack of research.

Is this some kind of test to check the new "be welcoming" policy? Is it just people happy that they've found a simple question they can answer? I can't remember the last time I saw 10 upvotes for an answer in the [algorithm] tag.

---

ADDENDUM:

Believe me, I'm not angry or frustrated (or even trying to get the question downvoted or closed per sé), I'm just genuinely puzzled.

Comment: Your second paragraph seems to be making lots of assumptions based on little facts and frustration. I'll write a detailed answer soon.

Comment: @PaulStenne That may be true :-) Even so, I'm really puzzled by how this question was received.

Comment: Meh: y=mx+c.  'I dropped maths at school', no kidding.  What is the point in users  dropping maths, trying to write software and then asking SO contributors to prop them up?   It's just cucumbers bottom-feeding:(

Comment: It has a lot of upvotes because people probably found it through the javascript tag, not the algorithm tag.

Comment: How have you managed to go so long without seeing problems like this?  I can't make it through a single page without seeing multiple low quality questions attracting upvotes an answers.

Comment: Earlier, on my way back from lunch, I saw a huge 18-wheeler full of paint.  Looking at those answers, I can only assume that the paint was delivered.  [(Of course, this is entirely tongue in cheek.)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bikeshedding)

Comment: @m69 what off-topic reason are you proposing to close it as? Given the number of answers it appears not to be either too-broad or unclear.

Comment: @RobertLongson "not a programming problem but a math one"

Comment: @chevybow Well then the fact that the question opens by saying that it's not actually a javascript question would lead one to believe that javascript programmer would be even *less* likely to think it was a good question.

Comment: @user2285236 Where's that in the list of close vote reasons? If we exclude all problems that contain any mathematics there won't be much left.

Comment: @RobertLongson It's in the bottom where you fill in the blanks for "I am voting to close this question as off-topic because ..."

Comment: @RobertLongson No one said that any question that contained any mathematics isn't on topic.  What was said is that a question that *isn't about programming* is off topic.  You can see as much in the help center in the on-topic section if you're interested in details.  A question not actually being about programming is off topic on SO.  There are some math sites where math questions can be on topic (I have no idea if this particular math question would be on topic on any of them though, so be sure to check their help centers).

Comment: @Servy:  I could see an argument in which a question about an algorithm that does this could be on topic, since algorithmic questions *are* on topic here.  This question does not rise to that occasion, though.

Answer (score 7):

Let's take a moment to filter out the noise of the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50589970/1).

Original take:

> I need to write a formula in javascript but any coding languge would
>   do or even just maths.
>
> I am trying to transform some data. Currently i am using the google
>   natural language api to return scores of between -1 and 1 based on
>   sentiment of some text.
>
> I need to change the output so that -1 (min) is represented by 1 and 1
>   (max) is represented by 10. This would mean that a score of 0 (mid)
>   returns 5.5.
>
> I dropped maths at school...
>
> Could anyone help? I feel like this is beyond me.

Filtered take:

> I need to write a formula in javascript.
>
> I am trying to transform some data.
>
> I need to change the output so that -1 (min) is represented by 1 and 1
>   (max) is represented by 10. This would mean that a score of 0 (mid)
>   returns 5.5.
>
> Could anyone help? I feel like this is beyond me.

I don't see how this question could be on-topic given that it reads like a requirements dump.  We have homework questions which read *very* similar to this, and wouldn't even rise to the occasion of a Meta post.

Questions like this should be closed as "too broad".  They're asking too much of us in that they want us to *teach* them, instead of us *helping* them.

Answer (score -13):

You seem like you're posting a Meta question out of frustration and to trigger a witch hunt on the question. This approach is poor.

As for the question, it's a fairly well-formed question that could use a couple edits.
Its topicness is *okay*. It's clear, focused, about programming, language-agnostic. The [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag could definitely be removed.
It's a very simple question.
It could be useful to future readers.

Overall it seems fine to me.

Comment: I disagree.  Looking at it with any other visor would imply "too broad".  As an expert I would demand *some* amount of effort from the OP towards this question, and all I see are requirements.

Comment: @Makoto lack of effort is a reason to downvote, not close.

Comment: @Makoto Which visor? And amount of effort is a quality metric, not a scope one.

Comment: @RobertLongson:  "...and all I see are requirements."  That's enough reason to close as "too broad" in my book.

Comment: @PaulStenne:  I'll refer you to my previous comment.

Comment: @Makoto If the requirements are specific, where's the issue?

Comment: The issue then becomes one of scope.  If someone uses Stack Overflow in this way, they then think it's acceptable to just give us a list of requirements and we will swoop in and code their solution for them.  The easiest to define and the most reviled are homework questions, in which some poor student posts their assignment in the hopes that someone will write their assignment for them.  It's happened plenty of times before.  It doesn't mean that it has to *keep* happening.

Comment: It also leads to a severe corruption in the ultimate goal of Stack Overflow, which is to be a repository of detailed answers to every programming question.  I admit that it's fine to ask questions about an algorithm, but we as a community have the obligation to draw the line in the sand on what we do and do not accept.

Comment: @Makoto Yeah tbh I agree it sucks. I don't really like this kind of question neither. However, under the current rules, and despite the mid- and long-term negative effects they bring, they're on-topic.

Comment: No, seriously, I'm genuinely puzzled. I spent 10 minutes looking at the page trying to find out why this question received so many answer and upvotes within its first hour after being asked.

Comment: @m69 Tim [lost his keys again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/306392).

Comment: @PaulStenne:  There are at least five people who disagree that this question is "on-topic".  Not sure where you're getting this information from...

Comment: @Makoto Come on, both of us know exactly how it goes when _any question link_ is posted on Meta for a scope issue... Your last point isn't exactly relevant.

Comment: @PaulStenne Lots of people post meta questions saying a question should be closed/opened/etc. only to be told that, no, what had already happened to that question was correct (and why), and where the action proposed isn't taken.